# Reproduce PIPE functionality in IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, stdout, stdin, pipe

I am hoping some genious out there can help me out with this...

I am using sox to merge and resample a group of WAV files, and pipe the output directly to the input of NeroAACEnc for encoding to AAC format.

I originally ran the process in a script, which included:

```
sox.exe d:\audio\1.wav d:\audio\2.wav d:\audio\3.wav -c 1 -r 22050 -t wav - | neroAacEnc.exe -q 0.5 -if - -of test.m4a
```

This worked as expected. The '-' in the comand line translates as 'Pipe/redirect input/output (stdin/stdout)' - So Sox pipes to stdout, and NeroAACEnc reads from stdin, the | joins them together.

I then migrated the whole solution to Python, and the equivalent command became:

```
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE
runwav = Popen(['sox.exe', 'd:\audio\1.wav', 'd:\audio\2.wav', 'd:\audio\3.wav', '-c', '1', '-r', '22050', '-t', 'wav', '-'], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
runm4b = call(['neroAacEnc.exe', '-q', '0.5', '-if', '-', '-of', 'test.m4a'], shell=False, stdin=runwav.stdout)
```

This also worked like a charm, exactly as expected. Slightly more convoluted, but hey :)

Well now I have to move it to IronPython, and the Subprocess module isn't available (the partial implementation that is, doesn't have Popen/PIPE support - plus it seems silly to add a custom library when there is probably a native alternative). **UPDATE** The partial module DOES support Popen and PIPE, I mis-read it. It is possible to extract the specifics for the .net/IronPython solution from this module (see update below)

I should mention here, that I opted for IronPython over C#, because I am comfortable with Python now - however, there is a chance of moving it again later to C# native, and I am using IronPython to ease myself into it :) I have no C# or .net experience.

So far I have the following equivalent, that sets up the 2 processes:

```
from System.Diagnostics import Process
wav = Process()
wav.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
wav.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
wav.StartInfo.FileName = 'sox.exe'
wav.StartInfo.Arguments = 'd:\audio\1.wav d:\audio\2.wav d:\audio\3.wav -c 1 -r 22050 -t wav -'       
wav.Start()

m4b = Process()
m4b.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
m4b.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
m4b.StartInfo.FileName = 'neroAacEnc.exe'
m4b.StartInfo.Arguments = '-q 0.5 -if - -of test.m4a'
m4b.Start()
```

I know that these 2 processes start (I can see Nero and Sox in the task manager) but what I can't figure out (for the life of me) is how to string the two output/input streams together, as with the previous two solutions. I have searched and searched, so I thought I'd ask!

If anyone knows either:

1. How to join the two streams with the same net result as the Python and Commandline versions; or
2. A better way to acheive what I am trying to do.

P.S. A code sample based off the above would be awesome :) or a specific code example of a similar process that I can easily translate.

[UPDATE]

After consideration, I resolved to handle my particular scenario as two seperate processes; outputting the merged WAVs to a file, then using that file as the input for the conversion.

However, it is possible to acheive what I wanted, using the subprocess module available [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.ironpython.com/msg05495.html).

Comment: IronPython, as of 2.7, has a complete subprocess implementation included.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has named pipes and you can use them from .NET applications like IronPython. It is usually straightforward to translate VB.NET examples [like this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/dotnetnamedpipespart1.aspx). You can often find managed libraries for things like this, for instance http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/dotnetnamedpipespart1.aspx

Here is another project to create a wrapper around the pipe api. http://omegacoder.com/?p=101

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for the response. I know I have wav.StandardOutput and m4b.StandardInput available, but no matter what combination I try, I can't seelf to get is working; e.g. I'd expect it to be something like m4b.StandardInput.BaseStream = wav.StandardOutput.BaseStream - but that throws an exception.

Comment: If you had read the VB.NET example above, you would not expect something as simple as an assignment statement to work. Interprocess communication is complex. You can hide the complexity inside a class/module but first you need to understand it all and make it work.

Comment: I did read the article, thank you for the link. However, the complexity led me to beleive that a process that is simple in both commandline and Python, must have an analogous solution in .net. Maybe I am wrong, but I have read a lot of articles referencing the StandardOutput and StandardInput methods available from the Process class. I'll keep searching, and update my post when I find the solution (no matter how complex!). Thanks again.